# Seemingly random value for variable defined in switch block

Tags: c, variables, scope

In C, you can define a variable at the beginning of any block.

For example, the following is correct (although setting `i` to 5 is weird):

```
    int i = 5;

    for (i=0; i<1; i++) {
        int j = 1;
        printf("Value FOR: %d\n", j);

    }
```

Strangely, when doing this in a `switch`, the value of `j` seems random.

```
    int i = 5;

    switch (i)
    {
        int j = 1;
    default:
        printf("Value SWITCH: %d\n", j);
        break;
    }
```

The piece of code above prints the following on my machine: `Value SWITCH: 8` (while it should be `Value SWITCH: 1`)

Any idea why?

Could it be because in `default` block, it is actually not instantiated and it reads in random memory?

FYI: I am using gcc version 4.6.1 on Windows, if that matters.

Comment: I think, that he jumps immediately to the default so, thats why, because he always jump to the labels! Maybe this can help you understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866193/variable-definition-inside-switch-statement

Comment: This can help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement